# How do I install custom ROM on HUAWEI Honor 4A?

Tags: google-play-store, rooting, rom-flashing, stock-rom, vanilla-android

I have a Chinese HUAWEI Honor 4A and want to install a different OS without the bloatware and restrictions that come with it (eg no play store).

Any recommendations on which path to choose?

I just want a simple, stable, hassle free OS and the tips on the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ROOT your device first.

This link helps you to ROOT and install custom [Recovery](http://www.stechguide.com/root-and-install-twrp-recovery-on-huawei-y6-honor-4a/) on your device.

You can download custom [ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/t/huawei-y6) from here.

After rooting and installing custom Recovery(TWRP), Download ROM file zip,GApps zip(if you need to install Google apps), .

1. Reboot to recovery mode.
2. Prepare a backup of current ROM (IMPORTANT). In TWRP, select backup, and check System, Data, Boot, and select backup.
3. After that, go back and select Wipe, select System, Data, Boot, Caches. Wiping deletes all your data.
4. Then, go back and select Install, and select zip file.
5. And you can install Gapps, select Install, and select zip file.